# Como hallar la suma de los numeros ingresados

Tags: java

```
    double suma=0;
    totalInporte = (int)iP;
    for(int i=0; i < 5;i++) {
        suma = suma +totalInporte;
    }
    System.out.println(totalInporte);
```

*Buenas tardes amigos tengo que hacer un programa que sume el total del importe a pagar,
mi código solo funciona cuando los números son iguales*

Alguna ayuda por favor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estas sumando siempre totalInporte. que es lo que queres sumar realmente?

Comment: Buenas tardes Cristopher: No entiendo claramente lo que intentas hacer pero a mi parecer tendrías que devolver suma.
recuerda el comando += para agilizar tu código.
¿Como lees los números que vas a sumar? double suma=0; totalImporte = (int)iP; for(int i=0; i < 5;i++) { suma += totalImporte; } System.out.println(suma);

Comment: Creo que para poder ayudarte necesitaríamos ver más código. Por ejemplo, como lees los números que vas a sumar? Es por entrada manual del teclado?